# numberOfSectionsInTableView for 2 different cells in the same controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view that has 2 independent cells. Everything is working properly, except the `numberOfRowsInSection` return that must be different for each cell.

I want my cell "dummy" to only return 1 or 2.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //I need to add some code in here that will say that
    //if my cell = dummy then return 1 else

    //Returning table count based on number of Team Names
    return _teamNames.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return indexPath.row + 20 - indexPath.row;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 18) {
        return indexPath.row + 50 - indexPath.row;
    } else {
        return indexPath.row + 26 - indexPath.row;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *dummycell = @"dummy";
    dummytest *cellar = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:dummycell 
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cellar.righthere.text = @"hello";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StandingsIdent";

    StandingsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
                                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: That does not really make sense. `numberOfRowsInSection` must return what the name indicates: the number of rows in a table view section. How can that be dependent on the cell? - Btw. what are you trying to achieve with a calculation like `return indexPath.row + 50 - indexPath.row;` ?

Comment: i still have some cleanup to do, but at that time it was doing exactly what i needed.

Comment: Please clarify what your problem is or what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{



// I need to add some code in here that will say that if my cell = dummy then return 1 else

// You need to set this bool value in your code somewhere - where you have some sort of toggle button between - Dummycell and StandingsViewCell
    if(isDummyCell) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
       return _teamNames.count; // Returning table count based on number of Team Names
    }


}
```

Comment: the (IsDummyCell) is not working :p i tried every combination

Comment: You need to set bool value isDummyCell somewhere in your app - where you are implementing some sort of switch functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NSMutableDictionary as source for your Table View data (i.e. "MyData"), so you can control the behaviour of every cell directly by the data source.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //list of elements
    if (self.keys.count == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    NSString *key = [self.keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *mySection = [MyData objectForKey:key];
    return [mySection count];

}
```

where keys is the array that holds your sections. When you load your data, if you want an alphabetical order, you've only to do:

```
NSMutableArray *keyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[keyArray addObjectsFromArray:[[self.MyData allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
self.keys = keyArray;
```

Comment: I would not recommend a *dictionary* as table view data source. There is no guarantee about the order of the keys returned by `[MyData allKeys]`. Better use an *array*.

Comment: I've edited the answer with NSArray of section alphabetically sorted.

Comment: hm im not sure if this is what i need. I need something like... if cell identifier is this, return this, if cell identifier is that, return that.